# Solving the problem of SQLinjection

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net, authentication, sql-injection

For my login control I'm using parameters in an SQL statement. Trouble is if people use SQLinjection, I'm afraid they'll be able to get in too.

I have two textboxes and the values are passed on to an SQL statement, this checks whether the values are found in the DB.

Is there a way to make sure this isn't possible? I know in PHP you need to use something infront of the textboxes.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use parameters in your queries:

```
// C#
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Products SET description = @Description WHERE id = @ID");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", "something");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 123);
```

And the equivalent in VB.net:

```
// VB.net
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("UPDATE Products SET description = @Description WHERE id = @ID")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", "something")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", 123)
```

Comment: Nice example... note he did select VB.Net as one of the tags :-)

Comment: Very nice indeed. Does it matter whether you use @Description or ?, because I can only seem to use ?.

Comment: and I seemed to have clicked SQL, instead of MySQL :$ but this is the same I presume? 
Dim cmd as new OdbcCommand(" .... ")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(" .. ", ...)

Comment: @Tom sorry I fixed a typo in the answer.  Your @Description in the query should match the @Description parameter specified below it.  Then it knows which value to pick.

Comment: thank you Tom :) You wouldn't also know HOW this works? Like why does this work and a normal query not?

Comment: I'm not super expert on this but take a look as MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx (it also states it doesn't support `?` as you asked).  It works because if you just have a single string, it wont know where the values start or end, if you paramtatise it, it has the additional information of knowing that this string is being inserted specifically for this value, there is no ambiguity over where the value starts and ends.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use SqlParameter.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterised queries are recommended

See example below

```
Private Sub DisplayPersonData(ByVal first_name As String, _
    ByVal last_name As String)
    ' Open the connection.
    connUsers.Open()

    ' Make a Command for this connection
    ' and this transaction.
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand( _
        "SELECT * FROM People WHERE FirstName=? AND " & _
            "LastName=?", _
        connUsers)

    ' Create parameters for the query.
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New _
        OleDb.OleDbParameter("FirstName", first_name))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDb.OleDbParameter("LastName", _
        last_name))

    ' Execute the query.
    Dim db_reader As OleDbDataReader = _
        cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow)

    ' Display the results.
    If db_reader.HasRows Then
        db_reader.Read()
        txtFirstName.Text = _
            db_reader.Item("FirstName").ToString
        txtLastName.Text = _
            db_reader.Item("LastName").ToString
        txtStreet.Text = db_reader.Item("Street").ToString
        txtCity.Text = db_reader.Item("City").ToString
        txtState.Text = db_reader.Item("State").ToString
        txtZip.Text = db_reader.Item("Zip").ToString
    Else
        For Each ctl As Control In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf ctl Is TextBox Then ctl.Text = ""
        Next ctl
    End If

    ' Close the connection.
    connUsers.Close()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Stored Procedures and a database abstraction layer (ORM)

Comment: Unfortunately, my hostingwebsite has updated its database and Stored Procedures aren't available at the moment -.-

Answer (score 0):

If you have the appropriate server-side permissions, you can create stored procedures to accept the parameters rather than assigning an update statement to the command object. SPs also provide better performance than dynamic DML statements.

Comment: I know, but my provider doesn't support Stored Procedures atm.