# ASP.NET parameters calling in SQL command (code behind)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

how to call an asp parameter in a sql command
exp:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT name FROM server WHERE code="+TextBox1.Text;
```

is it correct? .

Comment: it is NOT. check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043389/solving-the-problem-of-sqlinjection

Comment: and indeed, obligatory http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 6):

*(tries and fails to suppress a shudder)*

```
 cmd.CommandText =  "SELECT name FROM server WHERE code=@code";
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("code", TextBox1.Text);
```

otherwise, you are just ripe for SQL injection.

### NEVER CONCATENATE USER-INPUT INTO COMMANDS