# I am trying to insert values from a datetimepicker into a database in C# but I get an error

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to insert values from a datetimepicker into a database, but I get an unhandled exception

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

This is the code I used:

```
private void bunifuFlatButton8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OrderID.Text == "" || CustomerID.Text == "" || CustName.Text == "" || AmountTB.Text =="")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fill the data correctly");
    }
    else
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into OrderTB values(" + OrderID.Text + "," + CustomerID.Text + ",'" + CustName.Text + "','" + OrderDate.Text + "'," + AmountTB.Text + ")", Con);
        Con.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Order successfully added");

        Con.Close();
        populate();
    } 
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You have many problems with that little bit of code, but if `OrderDate` is the datetimepicker, user `OrderDate.Value` to pass a date to the database.  Then rush to the Microsoft docs site to learn how to properly use those database provider objects.

Comment: Don't use parameter for SQL, use the proper way to provide parameter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6043389/solving-the-problem-of-sqlinjection

Comment: Changing OrderDate.Text to OrderDate.Value solved my problem. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and I'll make sure to learn more about database provider objects :D

Comment: @xeyon why have you deleted your comment after confirming the answer?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to comment it to the other guy's answer but I also learned a lot from your answer sir, thank you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use the code below. If you want to use try and catch use it to get the error and Instead of OrderDate.Text use OrderDate.Value to get DateTime value and convert it to string in desired format as below

```
private void bunifuFlatButton8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (OrderID.Text == "" || CustomerID.Text == "" || CustName.Text == "" || AmountTB.Text =="")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fill The data Correctly");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            //Instead of OrderDate.Text use OrderDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") then you will have correct format for SQL Insert
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into OrderTB values(" + OrderID.Text + "," + CustomerID.Text + ",'" + CustName.Text + "','" + OrderDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff") + "'," + AmountTB.Text + ")", Con))
            {
                Con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Order Successfully Added");
                Con.Close();
                populate();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("I got an error : " + ex.Message); // This will give you error message instead of stopping your program
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: No, please don't do this. 1. NEVER create SQL statements from string concatenation (beware of [SQL injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/)) and 2. dont' pass DateTime as string to the database, but as DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

As@Ňɏssa Pøngjǣrdenlarp mentioned in the comment you have to use the Value in the proper format, which should be `DateTime`.

You have a couple of issues in your code, let me highlight them below.

1. you should use `using` with the connection to dispose of them.
2. Put your code properly in the try-catch, not like it's mentioned in
   the code. You should use parameterized queries to avoid SQL
   injection.
3. Handle the `null` case as well if the Text is `null`.
4. you can also utilize the return value of `ExecuteNonQuery`.